# Here Maps marker on Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: display, here-api, markers, mobile-devices

The markers displayed on the page https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/infoBubbles/open-infobubble on a Samsung Galaxy S7 are extreemly small and not clickable. This makes Here Maps Javacript API useless for this mobile application. Ias there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to open a web application in your mobile or are you trying to build an android application which has an info bubble?

Comment: I'm trying to open a web applicaton on my mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Check the source code of the web page whether the environment uses hi-res maps. Below is a sample code snippet.

```
var hidpi = ('devicePixelRatio' in window && devicePixelRatio > 1);
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers(hidpi ? 512 : 256, hidpi ? 320 : null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The divicePixelRatio is indeed a factor.
I have resolved the issue bij using

```
    var iconOptions = {
        // The icon's size in pixel:
        size: new H.math.Size(18 * pixelRatio, 24 * pixelRatio),
        // The anchorage point in pixel, 
        // defaults to bottom-center
        anchor: new H.math.Point(9 * pixelRatio, 24 * pixelRatio)
    };
```